# Add a confirmation step on file upload

Tags: files

I'm trying to add a confirmation step when I upload a file (file_entity).  After I upload a file that exists already on the server, I want the user to be asked if he really wants to replace the existing file with the new one.

I can detect wether or not a file already exists on the site but I'm not sure how to add another step in the process before the file is saved ...

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to where to start ?

Comment: Are you using [File Hash](https://www.drupal.org/project/filehash)? If not, I would recommend it. It's much more reliable than checking for duplicates against filename or some other fuzzy criteria. It will also allow you to turn off duplicate file uploads globally. Per-user confirmation has been submitted as a [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/1910372) but unfortunately there isn't much action on it. Probably because it's gotta be a tricky thing to implement. Sorry I don't have an answer for you.